# storyboard dynamic auto layout issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have this situation :

[image]

When I tap on "add" button I reduce the pink view's(first view) height and I execute this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewPink: UIView!

    @IBAction func add(_ sender: AnyObject) {


        viewPink.frame = CGRect(x: viewPink.frame.origin.x, y: viewPink.frame.origin.y, width: viewPink.frame.size.width, height: viewPink.frame.size.height - 50)

        }
```

but I want that the last view remains to the same distance from the pink view , essentially you have to climb on why the pink view reduces its height , instead the second view remains where it was before.

Can you help me about it?

P.S I set the vertical spacing constraint between the two views but It doesn't work

Comment: If you are using autolayout and constraints, then you need to alter the constraints, not mess around with the frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add an Height constraint on your pink view, create an IBOutlet to this constraint in your ViewController, and set the "constant" property to change the height.

Example:

`heightConstraint.constant = 150`

This will change the height with Autolayout, you shouldn't change the height by setting a new frame because it doesn't use Autolayout.